# Getting undefined while access index parameter while iterating over objects in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Please refer below code. Here I am using `v-for` to iterate over the object.

In this I am trying to access index parameter but I am getting it blank.

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="(event, key, index) in events">
    index is {{index}}
</a>
```

I also tried below way but got the same result:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="event in events">
    index is {{$index}}
</a>
```

This is my object:

```
var events = [{
            name: 'event1',
            description: 'description 1',
        },
        {
            name: 'event2',
            description: 'description 2',
        }
    ];
```

Can anybody please help me out with this. How can I access index property here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of what type is your `events` object?

Comment: `events` is type of array.. In which I am storing objects...Please refer the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your `events` object's json formatting. Try the following:

You `JSON` string also seems to be incorrect. The field description should be quoted as well as the answers. remove the comma after the description data

```
 [{
            "name": "event1",
            "description": "description 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "event2",
            "description": "description 2"
        }
    ]
```

In some cases due to the `JSON` formatting you might have an object containing an array:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="(event, key, index) in events.**events**"> //events can be .data or events[0]
    index is {{index}}
</a>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JLC007/xbudwbLk/1/)**

Comment: great! try and use this tool to validate your JSON - makes life a lot easier... https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1):

> [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Basic-Usage) also supports an optional **second** argument for the index of the
> current item

And there is no third argument. So you should write like this

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="(event, index) in events">
    index is {{index}}
</a>
```